# Flutter and Cloudflare Cookies - how to use it?

Tags: api, flutter, cookies, cloudflare, ddos

I have flutter app. my app is using some api. the site on which the api is hosted - uses Cloudflare  for protection. sometimes I get the following response:

```
<head>
<title>Access denied | app...com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" type="text/css"
    media="screen,projection" />
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script>
```

This means the site is under attack now(DDOS), but I need access to the api at any time. I found an option to use Cloudflare Cookies. but I'm not sure if it works, am I on the right way? any tips I would be grateful.

Comment: Could  you please provide more infos about how you do the request

Comment: It is better to provide more information regarding what you are looking for such as what do you use, etc..

Comment: What's the URL?

Answer (score 1):

The website is using Cloudflare which is a security and content delivery product.
When Cloudflare is used, all traffic to the website goes through Cloudflare first, where various security checks are made.
It helps to prevent things like malicious bots and attacks on the website.

The error means you have been blocked from accessing the resource. This is probably because the firewall at Cloudflare has decided the request from your mobile is malicious or unwanted, so it's blocking you. The website works fine when you visit using your browser because this is considered a "normal" request.

Use this code to simulate a browser:

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('URL'),
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36', });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the http headers for that API, and pass it (probably in `get` method).